# n/ is showing up in .readline()

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

So, I am trying to write a txt file with n/, so I do something like this,

`txtfile.write("Hello.n/")`
but when I do
`txtfile.readline(1)`
the output is:
`Hello.n/`
Even though in the actual txt file, it says "Hello." normally..

Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: `txtfile.write("Hello.\n")`

Comment: @ChrisCharley
Like I said, when I do that, it comes up as "Hello.n/" when I do `txtfile.readline(1)`

Comment: @Kaden_Wastlund You aren't distinguishing between `"\n"` (which is a newline) and `"n/"` (which is just two regular characters).

Answer (score 3):

```
txtfile.write("Hello.n/")
```

Firstly this is probably not what you wrote

```
txtfile.write("Hello.\n")
```

You wrote the above and the \n (new line operator) added to the end is a newline, it is part of the original text so the readlines() function gives you that

```
txtfile.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

If you do want to get rid of the newline use this to remove the newlines

Comment: yes you are right, answer was updated to readline()

Answer (score 0):

I'm reluctant to answer as I am also going to vote to close as a typo. The first part of the answer by @aanish-amir-waseem is what I think your issue is.

For clarity let me add a few snippets for you to try:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as file_out: file_out.write("Hello.\n")
with open("file.txt", "r") as file_in: print(repr(file_in.readline()))
```

This will produce a file that "looks" like "Hello." with an invisible newline at the end. When this code runs the `repr` will show you it as:

```
'Hello.\n'
```

Your code (that I believe has a little typo) does:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as file_out: file_out.write("Hello.n/")
with open("file.txt", "r") as file_in: print(repr(file_in.readline()))
```

This produces a file that looks (with or without the repr) like:

```
'Hello.n/'
```

Escape characters like `\n` and `\t` have the backslashes before the thing they escape. Your `n/` is ultimately two regular characters an `n` and a forward slash `/`.